# Well pressure switch sticking at cutoff setting

Tags: plumbing

I replaced my shallow well pressure switch after the old one quit working, now the new one  works fine except it sticks at cutoff pressure and will not shout off on its own, I can just lightly touch it  and it will stop.
Reducing the cutoff pressure acts the same way, It acts like it is magnetized,,is this possible and how would I correct it??
Thanks,
Julian

Comment: Why not return it under warranty

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as *"works fine except it sticks at cutoff pressure"* - sticking at cutoff rather than cutting off is not working fine. At all.

If the pressure is rising to cutoff and **not going beyond it**, that is more likely a pump problem, and the pressure switch might need to be lowered a bit so the pump will *actually* cut off. It's probably set a tiny bit higher than the pump is able to manage. *This may indicate that the pump is worn and could use a rebuild.*

If the problem is the switch, the pressure would continue to rise beyond cutoff as the pump continues to run. And in that case you'd return the switch as defective, not "fine."